# SRM New field in SC not showing up

Tags: layout, sap-srm

I have been following an old guide ( https://blogs.sap.com/2012/03/22/add-custom-field-to-sc-and-powl/) to add a field to POWL but it doesn't work in my case.

It is required to add the "Supplier product number" to the layout.

[image: SPN]

Since it's an existing field, I thought it was simple. But it's not the case. Following the guide, the field required is in the structure "/SAPSRM/S_POWL_RESULT_SC_ITM", so no need to add it.

Next, in SPRO, Adjust POWL Layout, Search Criteria, and Pushbuttons, I added the field to different feeders (because it didn't work for any of the feeders I found, I thought it wasn't the right one .. so I played with all of them)

a) [image: SC]

b) [image: SC_ESS]

c) [image: SC_PROF]

After this, the next step is to check in program POWL_D01 the query that might be cached for this layout and to delete the cache. I deleted all the cache data related to the queries "SAPSRM_FEEDER_SC*" and the result is ...

The field is nowhere to be seen in my layout.

Could you point me into the right direction ?

Regards,

Marius

Comment: Hi guys, any ideas ?

Comment: Did you activate append structures and feeder classes?